# Display a field of a node that is referenced on another node via a relationship

Tags: views, nodes

I have two content types, "Stores" and "Offers." In the "Offers" content type, there is a CCK node reference field type that references the "Stores" nodes.  So essentially, I create a store and if the store has an offer, I create the "Offer" node and select the store with which it is associated.

I have a view (a default glossary view) that displays a list of stores. I would like to display the node titles of any offers that are associated with it but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have tried to add a relationship on the node reference field then add a field that uses the relationship but the result just appears blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went with something similar to Stefan's answer.  I created a module using `hook_views_pre_render` that checks the correct table against the node id to see if there are any related nodes.  The code is shown below.

```
<?php

/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_pre_render()
 */
function gretna_views_pre_render(&$view) {
    // Select the right view
    if ($view->name == 'stores_list') {
        // Check how many results there are
        $count = count($view->result);
        // For each result (reason we don't use foreach is every result is duplicated twice)
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            // Get the nid for this row
            $nid = $view->result[$i]->nid;
            // Check to see if the node has any related offers
            $result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {content_type_store_offers} WHERE field_offer_store_nid = %d", $nid);
            $result = db_fetch_array($result);
            // If not false, the row has offers
            if ($result !== FALSE) {
                $view->result[$i]->users_uid = "Yes";
            }
            // Else it doesn't
            else {
                $view->result[$i]->users_uid = "No";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view style template you can access the node reference value, load the related node and then do whatever you need with that. You don't need a relationship for this approach.

Comment: That is a possibility but I don't want to have to do this through a template as it is both more memory intensive and less flexible.